# Testing input for numbers (else repeat) - C

Tags: c

I have a problem. I have a working code but I need to redesign it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int num_input(char *vyzva)
{
    int input;
    while (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nIt is not a number! Please repeat.\n\n");
        printf("%s", vyzva);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    return input;
}


int main (void){
 int cislice;


 printf("Insert a number: ");

 cislice = num_input("Insert a number:");

 printf("Number is: %d", cislice);

return 0;
}
```

Main goal of the redesigned code is to check if the user ipnut is only number (same as working code).
I need to get this input by fgets function a then convert string to number.

For this test I can't use scanf. I was told that strtol function works for this, but I have no idea how. Can anyone show me, how to use strtol to check wether the input is number or some letters?

It's a homework.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behaviour*. Don't do this. As for strtol, what does our old friend Google have to say about it?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` results in *Undefined Behavior* on *most* systems. Instead create a simple function to do it. `void empty_stdin(void) { int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar(); }`

Comment: Please explain did you get any error while running the above code. If yes then please mention it.

Comment: You also want to handle `EOF` as well as `0` `scanf` returns, not just `!= 1`. As is, the user could never cancel input.

Comment: This question might be appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdrianW No, questions asking how to rewrite code with different functionality are definitely off-topic on CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From strtol manual:

*long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base); 

... 

If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid 

character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all, strtol()  stores 

the  original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0).  In particular, 

if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the entire  string 

is valid.*

This means that in your code you need to use a pointer 'endptr' to check if the first invalid character correspond  to the first non digit after the number.
You also make use of the fact that you can subtract two pointer to get the offset

```
#define BUFF 20

int num_input()
{
    long int res;

    char buffer[BUFF];
    fgets( buffer, BUFF, stdin);
    char * endptr = NULL;
    res = strtol( buffer, &endptr, 10);

    int len = strlen( buffer);

    if( len-1 > endptr - buffer)
    {
        //Handle wrong result
    }

    return res;
}
```

Basically what this does is check if the read input is longer than the amount of digits converted by strtol. 
If it is you handle your exception.

PS: The check will fail if you have whitespaces after the number!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework assignment, your teacher probably does not want you to use [`strtol`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-strtol/) either.

This is a classical exercise of understanding how characters are represented in a computer.

What is usually expected in this kind of assignment is that you run over the character array `gets` returned in a loop, and check what each cell contains.
If you find a cell that contains a character that is not a digit (0 - 9), you will know user entered something that is not a number.

Depending on how your specific assignment was worded, - + and . may also be valid (is the number expected to be integer?)

If you insist on using `strtol` you will need to know how pointers and pointers to pointers work.
If you do, you can use the result in `endptr` parameter to check where the first invalid character is and decide if input is a number based on that.

Keep in mind this will only work for integer numbers (no decimal point).